# Im building mysql php login system and people say mysql is outdated and I shouldn't use it

Tags: php, mysql

Is MySQL outdated now? I have been learning it on w3schools and just when I'd felt ready to have PHP read/write to the thing, people say it's not good anymore. One reason they'd given was it's security.

Should I bother continuing to learn it, and if not what should I use for the database and why?

Comment: MySQL is perfectly fine. But you should not use the old PHP libraries any more. Use the new ones: mysqli or pdo.

Comment: **STOP**. MySQL isn't dated it's just a database back-end, but w3schools sure is. The material on that site is notoriously bad, often superficial, riddled with security issues. It will give you seemingly quick results but won't teach you any of the important fundamentals, which can lead to a sort of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is hard and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a high-speed hash like MD5 or SHA1/2.

Comment: Mysql the DB system or mysql functions as opposed to mysqli functions?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL as a database is very much alive.  php has dropped support for the mysql api.  you have two choices mysqli and pdo.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Don't confuse "MySQL" the database with `mysql_query` the API.

Comment: PDO is also the baseline. There's even better options like an ORM.